# How to do a recursive main function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

So I wanted to make a program that prints out a ASCII triangle. The program asks you the height that you want your triangle to be and prints it out and does it until the number you put in is **7**, then it draws the traingle of height 7 and the program stops. The trinagle that is print out is made out of '*' if the number is even and '#' if the number is odd. I wanted to do that by recursively calling the **main** function

```
triangle level character = draw level character 1 
      where draw level character accumulator
             | level <=0 = putStr("")
             | level > 0 = do 
                 putStrLn (replicate level ' ' ++ replicate accumulator character)
                 draw (level-1) character (accumulator+2)

main = do
    number <- readLn :: IO Int
    if(number `mod` 2 == 0)
      then
        triangle number'*'
        main 
     else if (number == 7)
       then triangle number '#'
       else triangle number '#'
       main
```

The error i get is

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘IO () -> IO ()’
              with actual type ‘IO ()’
• The function ‘triangle’ is applied to three arguments,
  but its type ‘Int -> Char -> IO ()’ has only two
  In the expression: triangle number '*' main
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    if (number `mod` 2 == 0) then
        triangle number '*' main
    else
        if (number == 7) then
            triangle number '#'
        else
            triangle number '#' main
```

Comment: If you read the error message carefully, you see that it thinks you put `triangle number '*' main`, when clearly you just meant (and appeared to write) `triangle number '*'` with `main` on the next line of the `do` block. Which must mean there's some indentation issue which isn't readily apparent from the snippet you've given. Are you sure your question is a literal copy of the code you were running? Are you perhaps mixing spaces and tabs?

Comment: @RobinZigmond the code is the same, Not gonna lie I have some issues with the spaces and how everything is supossed to be allingned but I didn't use and tabs in this code

Comment: It's a pedantic tangent, but `main` is not a function; it's an `IO` action.

Comment: @chepner well to be fully pedantic, it is an `IO` _value_, which stands for / indicates / denotes an I/O action.

Comment: @chepner all in pursuit of clarity. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says:

```
• The function ‘triangle’ is applied to three arguments,
  but its type ‘Int -> Char -> IO ()’ has only two
  In the expression: triangle number '*' main
```

So the compiler has parsed your code as `triangle number '*' main`; this means that the line break between `triangle number '*'` and `main` is not being interpreted as a `do` block statement break, and the reason is that you’re not inside a `do` block! The same error follows in the later `else` clause for `triangle number '#' main`. The fix is to add a `do`:

```
main = do
    number <- readLn :: IO Int
    if(number `mod` 2 == 0)
      then do
        triangle number'*'
        main 
     else if (number == 7)
       then triangle number '#'
       else do
         triangle number '#'
         main
```

If you have trouble with Haskell’s layout rules, you can always use explicit curly braces `{` … `}` around blocks and semicolons `;` between block items, to check your understanding of how your code is being parsed.

```
main :: IO ();  -- end signature
main = do {  -- begin ‘do’
    number <- readLn :: IO Int;  -- end statement
    if (number `mod` 2 == 0)
      then do {
        triangle number '*';
        main;
      }
      else if (number == 7)
      then triangle number '#'
      else do {
        triangle number '#';
        main;
      };  -- end ‘do’, end statement (starting with ‘if…’)
};  -- end ‘do’, end equation
```

Aside, note that I put spaces around the character literal like `… number '*' …` instead of `… number'*' …`. Apostrophes are allowed in identifiers (as an ASCII approximation of the “prime” symbol  <kbd>′</kbd>  ), so if you changed this to `number'X'` then that would be parsed as a single name, `number'X'`, rather than a name `number` followed by a character literal `'X'`, which may be confusing.

Comment: explicit separators FTW! (I think the ending `;`s are superfluous....). concerning the indentation, I'd rather prefer the `if`, `else if` and `else` all indented to the same level (to better resemble the multi-way conditional) and the `then` parts all indented a bit more, but also all to the same indentation.

Comment: @WillNess: I was just following OP’s code for the indentation; I put separators where the layout rule would, but yeah, I think some of them are never necessary. I prefer to indent continuation lines for `if` like any other expression, and use `MultiWayIf` instead of `… else if …`, but you can avoid the indentation of `else` with GHC’s `DoAndIfThenElse`, which is on by default. It works by allowing a semicolon there, which you can also write explicitly: `do { if a; then b; else c; }`. That lets you treat `then` & `else` kinda like layout keywords, and always follow them with a newline & indent.

Answer (score 5):

First, you're missing a `do` here:

```
      then
        triangle number'*'
        main
```

The two lines after `then` are being interpreted together as `triangle number '*' main` (which is how it's quoted in the error message if you notice). In order to have the two lines interpreted separately as subsequent actions, they need to be inside a `do`:

```
      then do
        triangle number'*'
        main
```

And the same problem, plus ambiguous indentation, exists with the very last block. It should probably be:

```
else do
  triangle number '#'
  main
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Haskell is pretty hard for me, compared to other languages.

Comment: That's because you started out with other languages. It's like eating sugar all your life and then suddenly tasting spinach. Spinach is much better for your health, but you can't tell by tasting it.